Constraint to forbid NaN in postgres numeric columns using Django ORM
Postgresql allows NaN values in numeric columns according to its documentation here.
When defining Postgres tables using Django ORM, a DecimalField is translated to numeric column in Postgres. Even if you define the column as bellow:
from django.db import models

# You can insert NaN to this column without any issue
numeric_field = models.DecimalField(max_digits=32, decimal_places=8, blank=False, null=False)

Is there a way to use Python/Django syntax to forbid NaN values in this scenario? The Postgres native solution is to probably use some kind of constraint. But is that possible using Django syntax?
Edit: As willeM_ Van Onsem pointed out, Django does not allow NaN to be inserted to DecimalField natively. However, the DB is manipulated from other sources as well, hence, the need to have an extra constraint at the DB level (as opposed to Django's built-in application level constraint).

Django will not allow NaN to be entered, so unless the database is also "fed" from another source, NaN can not occur.

That is true. In my comment under your post I clarified that the DB is manipulated from other sources as well. @willeM_VanOnsem

yes, it was more as an "addendum" to the other post. Perhaps not relevant here, but for future readers. But regardless, it is always better to enforce at the database, so I would indeed strongly advise to use a constraint.

I don't have a PostgreSQL database to test against but you can try creating a database constraint using a lookup based on the IsNull looukup:
from decimal import Decimal
from django.db.models import (
    CheckConstraint,
    DecimalField,
    Field,
    Model,
    Q,
)
from django.db.models.lookups import (
    BuiltinLookup,
)


@Field.register_lookup
class IsNaN(BuiltinLookup):
    lookup_name = "isnan"
    prepare_rhs = False

    def as_sql(self, compiler, connection):
        if not isinstance(self.rhs, bool):
            raise ValueError(
                "The QuerySet value for an isnan lookup must be True or False."
            )
        sql, params = self.process_lhs(compiler, connection)
        if self.rhs:
            return "%s = 'NaN'" % sql, params
        else:
            return "%s <> 'NaN'" % sql, params


class Item(Model):
    numeric_field = DecimalField(
        max_digits=32,
        decimal_places=8,
        blank=False,
        null=False,
    )

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            CheckConstraint(
                check=Q(numeric_field__isnan=False),
                name="numeric_field_not_isnan",
            ),
        ]


Can you please elaborate a little on the logic of as_sql in your answer? Some comments in the code also help. Thanks!

@szamani20 You can look at the Django documentation for a field lookup. The as_sql generates the SQL for the lookup, which, in this case, is used to generate the database constraint so you will get a constraint on the database table with the text numeric_field <> "NaN".

Thanks! Will try this with postgres and mark it as accepted answer.

Postgres does not seem to like double quotes around NaN as it thinks of them as columns. Hence, the syntax that works for Postgres is like this: "%s = 'NaN'" and "%s <> 'NaN'".

@MT0 answered the question. I just want to add that if you use a DemimalField and manipulate data in Django, you can normally not insert NaN or Infinity in the database. Indeed, Django itself checks if the value is finite (NaN is not considered finite).
Django first "prepares" the values to be representable in the database, and it does that with the .get_db_prep_save(…) method [GitHub]:
def get_db_prep_save(self, value, connection):
    if hasattr(value, "as_sql"):
        return value
    return connection.ops.adapt_decimalfield_value(
        self.to_python(value), self.max_digits, self.decimal_places
    )
Which calls the .to_python(…) function. The .to_python(…) method [GitHub] then checks if the Decimal is finite:
def to_python(self, value):
    # …
    if not decimal_value.is_finite():
        raise exceptions.ValidationError(
            self.error_messages["invalid"],
            code="invalid",
            params={"value": value},
        )
It is of course better to add a constraint, since it might still be possible that some update queries eventually result in a NaN, but for simple insertions/updates through Django, this should not happen.

Thanks! Your point about updates through Django is very true. I could not change the value using the Admin Website. However, other sources were able to make such changes.
